# Laravel - Twitter/X API Integration For Creating New Posts

Tags: php, laravel, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm in the middle of a proof-of-concept work, related to Twitter/X API integration and automation. This step is for basic exploration, so the code is not production ready.

### Context:

- Laraval 10 (no flexibility to change - unless versions like 9 or 8)
- "php": "^8.1",
- Local dev environment (http://127.0.0.1)
- I created my Twitter/X FREE developer account 2 days ago

Twitter/X Developer account - User Authentication Settings:

- Read and write and direct message selected
- Request e-mail from users - toggled on
- Type of App: Native App (also tried with web app)
- App info:

  - Callback URI / Redirect URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/twitter/callback (working and tested)
  - Website URL: https://dockerpipelinewpv1aws.syncsystem.com.br (I have the subdomain, but not using yet - I tried to set up something like http://127.0.0.1:8000, but didn't accept)
  - Terms of Service: https://dockerpipelinewpv1aws.syncsystem.com.br/terms-of-service (doesn't exist)
  - Privacy Polycy: https://dockerpipelinewpv1aws.syncsystem.com.br/privacy-policy (doesn't exist)

My code is almost working perfectly. This is what I have set up in Laravel.

composer.json

```
"atymic/twitter": "^3.0",
```

.env

```
# Consumer keys:
TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY=123
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET=321

# Authentication Token (not OAuth 2.0)
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN=456
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET=654
TWITTER_API_VERSION=1.1
```

config\twitter.php

```php
return [
    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

    'api_url' => 'api.twitter.com',
    'upload_url' => 'upload.twitter.com',
    'api_version' => env('TWITTER_API_VERSION', '1.1'),

    'consumer_key' => env('TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'),
    'consumer_secret' => env('TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET'),
    'access_token' => env('TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN'),
    'access_token_secret' => env('TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET'),
    'bearer_token' => env('TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN'),

    'authenticate_url' => 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate',
    'access_token_url' => 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
    'request_token_url' => 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
];
```

app\Http\Controllers\TwitterController.php

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Atymic\Twitter\Facade\Twitter;
use Atymic\Twitter\Twitter as TwitterContract;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class TwitterController extends Controller
{
    private $twitter;

    public function __construct(TwitterContract $twitter)
    {
        $this->twitter = $twitter;
    }

    public function redirectToTwitter()
    {
        $authCallback = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/twitter/callback';

        $response = $this->twitter->usingCredentials(
            config('twitter.access_token'),
            config('twitter.access_token_secret'),
            config('twitter.consumer_key'),
            config('twitter.consumer_secret')
        )
        ->getRequestToken($authCallback);

        $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=' . $response['oauth_token'];


        session(['oauth_token' => $response['oauth_token']]);
        session(['oauth_token_secret' => $response['oauth_token_secret']]);


        return redirect($url);
    }


    public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request)
    {
        $oauthToken = $request->query('oauth_token');
        $oauthVerifier = $request->query('oauth_verifier');

        if (!$oauthToken || !$oauthVerifier) {
            return redirect()->route('twitter.error')->withErrors('Invalid OAuth response from Twitter');
        }

        // Ensure the oauth_token matches the one stored in the session.
        if ($oauthToken !== session('oauth_token')) {
            // TODO: Log the error or handle it as per your application's needs
        }

        try {

            $tokenCredentials = $this->twitter->usingCredentials(session('oauth_token'), session('oauth_token_secret'))
            ->getAccessToken($oauthVerifier);

            session([
                'twitter_access_token' => $tokenCredentials['oauth_token'],
                'twitter_token_secret' => $tokenCredentials['oauth_token_secret'],
            ]);

            // Post a tweet or perform other actions with the authenticated user's token credentials.
            if ($this->postTweet($request)) {
                // The tweet was successfully posted
                return response()->json(['status' => 'OAuth Success'], 200);
            } else {
                // The tweet was not posted
                return response()->json(['status' => 'OAuth Success, but error posting message'], 200);
            }


        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Handle errors, such as logging or displaying a message
            return redirect()->route('twitter.error')->withErrors('Failed to obtain access tokens from Twitter');

        }
    }

    public function postTweet(Request $request)
    {
        $status = $request->input('status', 'This is a tweet posted from my Laravel application using API v2.');

        try {
            $twitter = $this->twitter->usingCredentials(
                config('twitter.access_token'),
                config('twitter.access_token_secret'),
                config('twitter.consumer_key'),
                config('twitter.consumer_secret')
            );

            // Post the tweet
            $response = $twitter->postTweet(['status' => $status]);

            if (isset($response['data']) && isset($response['data']['id'])) {
                // return response()->json(['status' => 'Message posted', 'tweet_id' => $response['data']['id']], 200);
                return true;
            } else {
                // return response()->json(['status' => 'Error posting message', 'error' => $response], 500);
                return false;
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // return response()->json(['status' => 'Exception caught', 'error' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

routes\web.php

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\TwitterController;

Route::get('auth/twitter', [TwitterController::class, 'redirectToTwitter'])->name('twitter.login');
Route::get('auth/twitter/callback', [TwitterController::class, 'handleProviderCallback'])->name('twitter.callback');
Route::get('auth/twitter/post', [TwitterController::class, 'postTweet'])->name('twitter.post');
```

The methods `redirectToTwitter` and `handleProviderCallback` are working fine. I can authenticate and the callback works perfectly.

### Problem

The problem is with `postTweet`, more specifically, this line:

```php
$response = $twitter->postTweet(['status' => $status]);
```

When this line executes, it returns me this error message:

```
[453] You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product
```

Initially, I suspected it were the API version I was using `TWITTER_API_VERSION=1.1` as I read somewhere that the API version 1 was being deprecated. However, I switched that to `TWITTER_API_VERSION=2` and did an isolated test with the `auth/twitter/post` route, but the problem persisted.

### Other Hypophysis:

- Requires HTTPS access?
- Free account and doesn't allow me to post?
  Note: In the dashboard, it does say that I would have up to 1500 posts per month
- Not being done through the subdomain set up in the website field?
- Something missing in my app settings?
- I'm not using the API version 2 correctly?

Also, if anyone has a better working suggestion? Either with Guzzle, Laravel Http, Laravel Socialite, or any other dependencies, I would appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a problem with the plugin you are using, I advise you to use the plugin's issue tracker (on GitHub)... https://github.com/atymic/twitter/issues. That way, hopefully, the plugin's devs can figure out a help for you.

NOTE: The plugin doc says they support Laravel 5 to 8. You can consider that also.

Comment: Right. Maybe, I'll do an isolated test with older versions before opening an issue. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah.... You should try that. And if the plugin includes tests (Unit, PEST, etc), you should maybe run the tests also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just implementing Atymic Twitter with Laravel 10 today.

Here's what I did that got it to work:

- Use Twitter API v2
- Go to Developer Portal -> Your App -> Settings -> Authentication Settings -> App Permissions -> select Read and Write
- Go to Developer Portal -> Your App -> Keys and tokens -> Regenerate your Access Token and Secret so it comes with Read and Write Permissions

Additionally, according to the issues post, postTweet is only available for Twitter API v1 however the code provided by Github user @reliq is working for me:
https://github.com/atymic/twitter/issues/399#issuecomment-1254272114

```
use Atymic\Twitter\Contract\Http\Client;
use Atymic\Twitter\Facade\Twitter;

...

$querier = Twitter::forApiV2()->getQuerier();
$result = $querier->post(
    'tweets', 
    [
        Client::KEY_REQUEST_FORMAT => Client::REQUEST_FORMAT_JSON,
        'text' => 'my tweet'
    ]
);
```

Comment: Hey Charles,
I implemented your logic, but I still get a dumped response like this:
`A request error occurred. Client error: `POST https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{
  "title": "Unauthorized",
  "type": "about:blank",
  "status": 401,
  "detail": "Unauthorized"
}`
I opened a thread in Twitter Community Forum so they can check if there's something wrong with my account. Question: is your account also free (both twitter and developer)? I even changed the setting for just read and write and generated the new token, and it's the same.

Comment: Another question: did you manage to make it work through a local dev environment (http://127.0.0.1:8000 or http://localhost:8000)?

Comment: Also: I'm not using the OAuth 2.0 access tokens. What are the tokens you're using?

Comment: My apologies for late reply.

Yes, it works in local dev

Do not use OAuth 2.0 Client ID and Client Secret, instead use both

Consumer Keys: API Key and Secret
Authentication Tokens: Access Token and Secret

Comment: No problem. Is your twitter account a Free account or do you have any paid subscription (account or developoer)?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what happened, but now it started to work - local environment and free account.